# Django REST Framework: AttributeError: 'PhotoView' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Tags: python, django, oop, django-rest-framework

I have this code:

```
class UploadedPhotoView(GenericViewSet,
                    ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)


class PhotoView(GenericViewSet,
                CreateModelMixin,
                ListModelMixin):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    uploaded_view = UploadedPhotoView.as_view({'get': 'list'})

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        try:
            serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
        except IntegrityError:
            raise SuspiciousOperation

    @list_route(methods=('GET', ))
    def uploaded(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.uploaded_view(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )
```

After running the tests I got next:

```
File "/Users/denny/project/picme/api2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 376, in initialize_request
parser_context=parser_context
File "/Users/denny/project/picme/api2/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 151, in __init__
self.parser_context['encoding'] = request.encoding or settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET
AttributeError: 'PhotoView' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

So I find it like bug, but I think the problem is in the magic of rest framework.

If I rewrite the function `uploaded` like below then it works.

```
@list_route(methods=('GET', ))
def uploaded(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return UploadedPhotoView.as_view({'get': 'list'})(
        request, *args, **kwargs
    )
```

Comment: So, you already have the solution, what is the question about ?

Comment: What are you thinking about dependency injection? I think that I should inject instance of class, not a class